# Why warnings crashes openJDK-11 build?

Tags: java, gcc, gcc-warning, openjdk-11

I need to build following openJDK

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch jdk-11+28 https://github.com/openjdk/jdk.git
```

on aarm64 NAME="Simply Linux", VERSION="9.1 (Destiny)"

For that I run:

```
    bash ./configure
    make images > make.log
```

And it fails with following error (make.log)

```
Building target 'images' in configuration 'linux-aarch64-normal-server-release'
    Warning: No mercurial configuration present and no .src-rev
    Compiling 117 files for BUILD_java.compiler.interim
    Compiling 394 files for BUILD_jdk.compiler.interim
    Compiling 299 files for BUILD_jdk.javadoc.interim
    
    ERROR: Build failed for target 'images' in configuration 'linux-aarch64-normal-server-release' (exit code 2) 
    
    === Output from failing command(s) repeated here ===
    * For target hotspot_variant-server_tools_adlc_objs_dfa.o:
    /home/user/jdk/src/hotspot/share/adlc/dfa.cpp: In member function ‘const char* Expr::compute_external(const Expr*, const Expr*)’:
    /home/user/jdk/src/hotspot/share/adlc/dfa.cpp:724:14: error: ‘char* strncat(char*, const char*, size_t)’ specified bound 2048 equals destination size [-Werror=stringop-overflow=]
           strncat(string_buffer, "+", STRING_BUFFER_LENGTH);
           ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /home/user/jdk/src/hotspot/share/adlc/dfa.cpp:732:14: error: ‘char* strncat(char*, const char*, size_t)’ specified bound 2048 equals destination size [-Werror=stringop-overflow=]
           strncat(string_buffer, " + ", STRING_BUFFER_LENGTH);
           ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /home/user/jdk/src/hotspot/share/adlc/dfa.cpp: In member function ‘const char* Expr::compute_expr(const Expr*, const Expr*)’:
    /home/user/jdk/src/hotspot/share/adlc/dfa.cpp:746:14: error: ‘char* strncat(char*, const char*, size_t)’ specified bound 2048 equals destination size [-Werror=stringop-overflow=]
           strncat(string_buffer, "+", STRING_BUFFER_LENGTH);
           ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
    
    * All command lines available in /home/user/jdk/build/linux-aarch64-normal-server-release/make-support/failure-logs.
    === End of repeated output ===
    
    No indication of failed target found.
    Hint: Try searching the build log for '] Error'.
    Hint: See doc/building.html#troubleshooting for assistance.
```

What am I doing wrong?
Where can I submit a bug report about openjdk11, or discuss this issue?

Comment: If you are getting an error include it in the question, not an off-site resource.

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8214444

Comment: @JohnnyMopp sorry, I don't understand, is there a chance to build openJDK11 (any version) without modification of source code, or I can build only  openjdk 12?